# write a sql query to get all records from Table users

Tags: sql

Plese write a sql query to get all records from Table users which have NOT a corresponding record in table test_results :

Users :

```
_____________________
id  | name | test_id
_____________________
1   | Hans |10
2   |John  |20
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp plz go thro this ..you will get your answer

Answer (score 2):

If i got your **Question** right, i below `Query` will give you the **desired result**.

```
select *
from users 
where test_id not in
(
  select test_id
  from test_results
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE users.test_id NOT IN (SELECT testId FROM test_results)
```